# Ios Alert on first launch to set up notification

Tags: ios, notifications, uialertview

I have created a photography assignment generator app using dreamweaver/phonegap with some finishing touches in xcode.
I have set up a settings bundle where the user can set a daily reminder on on off.  it is preset to OFF, as i would rather not annoy people who don't want it.
Because i have done this using dreamweaver, I can't find a way to access the settings bundle, so the user has to go to settings, flick the switch, and reboot the app to have it take effect.

What I would like to do is have the app ask them the first time the app is launched whether or not they would like to set up a daily reminder.  If they tap yes, it should set the reminder setting to ON/YES, if no, it should continue on with the default set to no.
it would be even more awesome if I could have a "Maybe Later" button.

I am not great at programming, and it was a lot of work for me to get this working(thanks to help from the great folks on here and other sites on the net)
I have tried using various IF/THEN, but I can't get it to work.

So here is what I have so far...would appreciate it greatly if any of you would be able to help me figure this out.
Thank you
Noel Chenier

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOtions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

{

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
 registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];

NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *appDefaults =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"NO" forKey:@"enableNotifications"];
[defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
[defaults synchronize];

UILocalNotification *localNotif= [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (localNotif) {
    NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",localNotif);
}

/*NSArray *keyArray = [launchOptions allKeys];
 if ([launchOptions objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:0]]!=[nil)

 {
 NSURL *url = [launchOptions objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:0]];
 self.invokeString = [url absoluteString];

 }*/

return  [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty simple task, especially considering you're already using `NSUserDefaults`. All you need to do is store a `BOOL` in your defaults every time the app launches. For example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOtions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if(![defaults boolForKey:@"firstLaunch"]) {
        //this key has never been set - this is the first launch
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"firstLaunch"];

        //show your alert here that you only want to show on the
        //first application launch
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Some Title" 
            message:@"Some message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
            otherButtonTitles:@"Some Button", @"Another Button", @"One More Button", 
            nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rickay
I'm sorry, I am a real newb...how do I implement what you have with what I have?  When I try to add it in, I get errors all over the place...how would I modify my current code to add that in?

Comment: You only need to use my code within the method I wrote, starting with `NSUserDefaults` and ending with the first closing bracket. Honestly, if you don't know how to implement what I have there, you should do some research about objective-c and the iOS launch cycle. Here's a link to get you started: http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/app-launch-sequence-ios-revisited/

Comment: thanks for that.  I appear to have figured out where I was going wrong.  Now to add the alert! Most likely I'll screw that up too! :)